# Is Tupac Shakur alive?

Tags: mortality, celebrities

Did Tupac Shakur fake his own death?

Numerous conspiracy theories have developed over the years - one being that he is [somewhere in Cuba](http://www.mirror.co.uk/3am/celebrity-news/tupac-alive-well-cuba-any-7231355), but I feel that myth could easily be debunked or confirmed soon, since President Obama has enabled American tourism in Cuba.  No matter how much he has aged, I think his voice would be too recognizable by American tourists.

Comment: What evidence would it take to convince you he is dead? (If he is dead, this rumour has no reason to be debunked soon.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the Los Angeles Times, September 14 1996:](http://articles.latimes.com/1996-09-14/news/mn-43719_1_rapper-tupac-shakur)

> [Tupac Shakur] was pronounced dead at 4:03 p.m. at University Medical
>   Center of respiratory failure and cardiopulmonary arrest, a hospital
>   spokesman said.
>
> (...)
>
> Shakur was taken to University Medical Center, where surgeons removed
>   his right lung. He remained on a respirator in intensive care until
>   his death.

Of course, those who believe that Tupac faked his own death (or something like that) are unlikely to be convinced by this. (I mean, assuming that Tupac had the resources to pull that off, he should have at least thought of including the hospital in the conspiracy.)

However, OP doesn't mention any such details like the hospital lying, etc., so I see no need to evaluate that.

Various theories feature different pieces of alleged evidence that Tupac is alive. Since none of them are mentioned in OP, I've got nothing specific to assess. The list would be too long.

OP links to a newspaper article. That article discusses many claims. I'm not going to discuss those in detail either since OP doesn't present those claims. Therefore, it's outside of the scope of this answer. However, I'll note that the article itself does address those claims and presents arguments suggesting that they are false.